# Sharepoint Online: site collection owner's possible claim types?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Sharepoint site collection owners' LoginNames are [claims](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx).

After some experimenting, I've been able to create site collections with 4 different types of owners:

1. `c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|<GROUP-GUID>_o` : an O365 group
2. `c:0t.c|tenant|<UNKNOWN-GUID>` : "Company Administrator" in Sharepoint Admin console
3. `i:0#.f|membership|<USER-EMAIL>` : an O365 user
4. `i:0#.w|dprodmgd<123>\_spofrm_<123456>` : seems to be a system account

Are there any other claim types that can be set as a Sharepoint Online site collection owner, and how do I create them?

[This](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Site-Collection-Admin-in-Modern-Team-Sites/m-p/35460/highlight/true#M3214) is the best reference I managed to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are all kinds of "claims".

I've got many of the common SharePoint prefixes listed here: "SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online Built-In Accounts"

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2016/03/sharepoint-2013-and-sharepoint-online.html

Here's one of the better lists for the general topic. As this is pre-Office 365, it does not include O365 Groups.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx?Redirected=true

As far a creating them, you don't. They are created by the Claims provider (how the user authenticated) when the user logs in. In custom environments the user could have authenticated from AD, Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc. The prefixes exist so you can avoid duplicate user IDs when two users with the same name come from different authentication sources.  I.e. smith.mike from Facebook (i:0#.f|fb|smith.mike) vs smith.mike from Twitter (i:0#.f|tw|smith.mike). (these two examples are made up!)

Comment: Are all of these possible Sharepoint online site collection owners? For example,  Sharepoint online's admin console doesn't allow me to set "All Users" as an site collection owner, and I'm wondering if Sharepoint online has "typical FBA user"s.

Answer (score 1):

> Sharepoint online's admin console doesn't allow me to set "All Users" as an site collection owner

I can't imagine that you would ever want to do that! Not a good idea, but you can select "Everyone except external users".

> Are all of these possible Sharepoint online site collection owners?

The link above includes a table that shows what's used in SharePoint Online.

Things keep changing in Office 365. See here for more info on "Everyone" https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4089534/how-to-grant-the-everyone-claim-to-external-users-in-office-365

I don't think you could ever assign "Everyone" in SharePoint Online from the web browser, but you may be able to do so from PowerShell. You can assign "Everyone except external users" from the web browser.

You can emulate an Everyone group: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866612/everyone-all-users-and-authenticated-users-in-azure-active-directory

Comment: You're right: I don't want to do that, but I want to know if somebody else can, so I'll know how to handle it :)